# comparing 2 sql queries , for performance optimization but little confused with result

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

i have 2 queries , Q1 is original  and Q2 is new re written version of Q1 .

But when running a sql trace what i found Q1 always have higher cpu cycles but lesser duration compared to Q2 .
can some one throw some light on the possible causes. Thanks

Comment: Without more info I doubt anyone would be able to help. My only thought is Q2 is spending more time working with the disk resulting in less CPU, but longer duration.

Comment: Q1 might have a parallel plan Q2 might have a serial plan. All we can do is guess based on the info you have provided!

Comment: Q1 was like select t1.c1,t2.c1 from t1,t2 where t1.c2 = t2.c2 and Q2 is re written with proper joins select t1.c1,t2.c1 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.c2 = t2.c2 , and the actual query has 10 tables  joined in the Q1 format which i modified to joins in Q2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most circumstances and platforms, you will be IO bound as opposed to CPU bound.  What this means is that the read/write speed of the disk is a limiting factor as opposed to processor speed.

It sounds like you have a better execution plan in your revised query that is taking advantage of parallelism.  This means it has multiple threads running on portions of the data simultaneously, with higher CPU utilization (which is a good thing).

Comment: so Q2 is better ? and is there any other params to judge performance in cases where cpu cycles are less but execution time is more

Comment: The execution plan is the best way to compare.  Time in and of itself is too dependent on other factors (caching, other server activity, etc) to use for the primary measure of efficiency.